# reshape, concatenate and create new column from horizontal to verical dataframe

Tags: r, substring, concatenation, reshape

I have large dataset with some of it shown here

```
data<-read.table(text="SR_ID   GCS_pre_desc    EDA_pre_desc    GCS_post_desc   EDA_post_desc   HR_pre  SBP_pre DBP_pre HR_post SBP_post    DBP_post
1.00    5.800   5.240   1.400   5.500   88  127 57  83  143 83
2.00    3.300   5.580   5.300   6.020   57  153 63  69  108 51
3.00    1.300   5.700   3.700   7.100   77  121 64  81  98  44
4.00    10.400  3.370   9.000   3.030   54  121 39  69  145 65", sep="", header=T)
```

I want to reshape my data to

1. put identical column headings below each other eg HR_post below
   HR_pre
2. Create new column Pre vs. post
3. Concatenate column heading eg HR_pre vs.post (as shown in the screenshot below).

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Your example data code gives me `data.frame': 4 obs. of  1 variable:` which is not what you show in the image below.

Comment: Please remove the `sep=\t`

Comment: Thanks @dario. I edited it as suggested. and upvoting your comment

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I edited it as suggested and upvoting your comment. Please let me know your valuable input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -SR_ID, names_to = c(".value", "prevspost"), 
           names_pattern = "(.*)_(pre|post.*)")
```

Comment: @arkun Thanks  a lot. It partially works as I got 3 categories as follow (post_desc , post, pre) so I changed the header title to be consistent. The question now how to convert the resulting tibble to be datafram? Appreciate your help

Comment: @MohamedRahouma Just add `%>% as.data.frame` at the end

Comment: Thanks. Accepted as solution and upvoted. Please upove my question if possible. Till now I could not use `%>% as.data.frame ` . Please try to edit the code to guide me through this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @MohamedRahouma Do you want to remove the `desc` category

Comment: @MohamedRahouma Perhaps `data %>% rename_at(-1, ~ str_remove(.,"_desc"))  %>% pivot_longer(cols = -SR_ID, names_to = c(".value", "prevspost"), names_sep="_")`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works and upvoted. I am still looking for how to convert tibble to datafram

Comment: @MohamedRahouma What you need is `out <- data %>% rename_at(-1, ~ str_remove(.,"_desc")) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -SR_ID, names_to = c(".value", "prevspost"), names_sep="_")  %>% as.data.frame`

Comment: A tbl_df is also a `data.frame`, only difference is that it. add more attributes.  So, once you do `as.data.frame` it will remove those additional attributes